# Vue - How to access data inside beforeRouteLeave - In Component Guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Trying to access data inside beforeRouteLeave but everything is `undefined`

Code below

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  ...
</style>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'blog-new',
    data() {
      return {
        isBodyChanged: false,
        isPublished: false,
        isTitleChanged: false,
      }
    },
    created() {
      ...
    },
    beforeRouteLeave: (to, from, next) => {
      console.log(this.isBodyChanged) //<--undefined
      if (this.isBodyChanged) {
        return next(false)
      } else {
        return next()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an ES5 function instead of an arrow function. Using an ES5 function will make the `this` keyword equal to the instance of the component, whereas an arrow function uses [lexical scoping](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/).

```
beforeRouteLeave: function(to, from, next) {
  if (this.isBodyChanged) {
    return next(false)
  } else {
    return next()
  }
}
```

However, you can also use this shorthand which I find helpful. This evaluates to the same as above.

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  if (this.isBodyChanged) {
    return next(false)
  } else {
    return next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Dominic said. Also you should add your function in `methods`.

Answer (score 0):

for me i Change lib 
from

"vue-router": "^2.0.1"

to

"vue-router": "^3.0.1"

version 2 has error:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1288